# Proving this euclidean equality

Tags: geometry

Let $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$ both be chords of the same circle.
Let $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$ intersect at $E$.

Then why is $\overline{AE}\cdot \overline{EC}=\overline{DE}\cdot \overline{EB}$ ?

Comment: Hi new user! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we prefer to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here :)

Answer (score 3):

I got one simple proof but I don't think it's correct..

Join $A$ with $B$ and $C$ with $D$,

Then we have:
$\angle AEB  \cong \angle DEC$
$\angle BAE \cong \angle$CDE

By Triangles with two equal angles are similar we have $\triangle AEB\sim \triangle DEC$.

Thus:

$\frac{AE}{EB} =\frac{DE}{EC}$

Thus $AE\times EC = DE\times EB$

Comment: Its really simple and absolutely correct, but I mind its originality though .. ;)

Comment: It's a proposition from Book III of Euclid's Elements.  Compare with [Proof 2 here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersecting_Chord_Theorem) of the Intersecting Chord Theorem.

Comment: hey @hardmath thanx and really gr8 site you have given me..,

Comment: Another name of this result is called "power of a point". You maybe interested to know that the truth-ness of the result does not depend on whether the point of intersection (E) is inside or outside  the circle.